# Laravel Asgard CMS drop down from database in create view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, asgardcms

I am learning laravel and now trying laravel based asgard cms.
I don't have complete knowledge of laravel so stuck at something.

I have a package table in database, which holds - package name, price, id.

I have another table which holds clients data like - name, package, address.

What i want to achieve is when creating client, I should be able to assign him a package. I want drop down from package table in create view
Can somebody guide me?

Here is my Create view file.

```
<div class="box-body">
<p>

    {!! Form::normalInput('name', 'your name', $errors) !!}

    {!! Form::normalInput('package', 'your package', $errors) !!}


    {!! Form::normalInput('address', 'your address', $errors) !!}
    {!! Form::normalInput('zone', 'your zone', $errors) !!}

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Original Documentation Says:

```
{!! Form:: normalSelect(‘test’, ‘test’, $errors, [1,2,3]) !!} // Create view
{!! Form:: normalSelect(‘test’, ‘test’, $errors, [1,2,3], $object) !!} // Edit view
```

`[1,2,3]` is your choices, should be key value array ( option value, option label)

for example:

```
$choices = [
    1 => "It's First Choice",
    2 => "value of choice is 2",
   'abc' => "Select abc"
]

{!! Form:: normalSelect(‘test’, ‘test’, $errors, $choices) !!} // Create view
```

`keys is option values, 
values is option texts`

Source: https://asgardcms.com/docs/v3/core-module/form-macros#normal-select